# What happened to Mara Jade's lightsaber?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

In Timothy Zahn's novel *Allegiance*, Mara Jade, still as Emperor's Hand, uses a (violet-colored) lightsaber. In (Timothy Zahn's, again) *Heir to the Empire* and other parts of that trilogy she already doesn't have it (I don't think Karrde would trust anyone with a lightsaber back when she started to work for him). Is the fate of her weapon mentioned anywhere?

Comment: I always thought it wasn't 'her' lightsaber, but one she was given for the specific mission.  I may be wrong, though.

Comment: @Jeff, well, I think it wasn't 'her' lightsaber in Jedi meaning, i.e. not built by her, but granted by Palpatine. Although Keith's answer has put me in the right direction and I've just found an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I may be misremembering, but I think that was a ret-conned fix, done via an article in *Star Wars Gamer*; I believe she lost it during a duel with [Lumiya](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Lumiya).

*Edit* -- Ok; found some details via Star Wars Wiki:
Per an article "[The Emperor's Pawns](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Emperor%27s_Pawns)" in [*Star Wars Gamer*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Gamer_5):

> Under the alias Merellis, she was a Come-Up Flector for a Caprioril swoop gang. It was during that occupation that she lost the violet-colored lightsaber she had been given by Palpatine in an encounter with Lumiya.  Lumiya, sent by Ysanne Isard, found her and tried to bring her back to Isard, but Jade refused. The two dueled and Jade escaped, though she lost her lightsaber in the process.

Per the attributions on Wookieepedia, more info may be in [*Jedi vs. Sith: The Essential Guide to the Force*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Jedi_vs._Sith:_The_Essential_Guide_to_the_Force).

Comment: I've also found it, thanks to you mentioning Lumiya - http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Duel_on_Caprioril.

Comment: Excellent; interestingly, I notice that article is sourced by the same additional source as I found in Mara Jade's article; the Essential Guide.  May have to dig a copy up :)

Comment: And, for completeness' sake, during the events of the Thrawn trilogy, Luke gave Mara his father's lightsaber (the one he lost on Bespin) after recovering it from the clone Luuke. Thus she replaced the purple one with Darth Vader's original lightsaber.